# Get TextBox value from GridView cell

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a GridView containing template fields. Each template field contains a TextBox. Last column of the GridView contains SELECT command field.

On click of SELECT, I want to get the value of TextBox located in a cell of the selected row.

I tried:

```
((TextBox)GridView1.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

in Row_Updating event but it is not working.

I tried a similar variant of code in SelectedIndexChanged event of GridView but it gives error: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look inside of a Cell, not inside of a Row, try this:

```
((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[iCellIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

Where you need to supply `iCellIndex` - index of the cell that has the textbox.

Oh and use square brackets to indicate collection item.